# how to add elements to an array in a loop using php

Tags: php, arrays

I am dynamically trying to populate a multidimensional array and having some trouble.

I have a list of US states. Associative array like this $states[nc], $states[sc], etc. in my loop I want to append cities onto each state so $states[nc][cities] contains an array of cities. Im stuck with the logic.

```
foreach($states as $state) {
    $data[$state] = $state;

    foreach($cities as $city) {
      $data[$state]['cities'] .= $city;
     }
}
```

I know that concatenation is not correct, but I am not sure how to add elements to this array. I keep getting errors with array_push.

What's the correct way to add these elements?

Comment: replacing the inner foreach with just $data[$state]['cities'] = $cities; should do the trick.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The same way you add to an array when the key is not a concern:

```
$data[$state]['cities'][] = $city;
```

Comment: that did it! I was trying to overcomplicate it, but that gives me the correct result. Thanks!

Comment: @user9437856 yes, it's one line of code, it's not difficult to execute it and see.

Comment: @Jon, Thanks for the reply. I was trying to implement your issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977036/how-to-display-the-array-inside-array-output

Answer (score 16):

In PHP, you can fill an array without referring to the actual index.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($var in $oldArray){
$newArray[] = $var;
}
```

Comment: Much simpler syntax: $newArray = array_values($oldArray);

Comment: `foreach()` with `in`? Nope.  https://3v4l.org/0vmXZ

Answer (score 4):

To add an element, use empty brackets.

```
foreach($states as $state) {
    foreach($cities as $city) {
       $data[$state][] = $city;
    }
}
```

This will create an array like this

```
array(
  'nc' => array('city1', 'city2', ...),
  'sc' => array('city1', 'city2', ...)
)
```

See [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) under "Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax"

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($states as $state) {
    $data[$state] = $state;

    foreach($state->cities as $city) {
      $data[$state][] = $city;
    }
}
```

Using empty brackets adds an element to the array.