# How to query employee details and relate their performance metrics?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join, multidimensional-array

I am fetching the id, first name, and last name of all employees that are approved and not archived.  Then I am looping these results and using the ids to query other tables to collect some count data.

I tried the below code, but I am not getting the expected output.

```
$queryEmp = "
    SELECT id, firstname, lastname
    FROM tbl_employee as e
    WHERE is_archive=0 and is_approved=1
";
$getQuery= $this->db->query($queryEmp);
$result= $getQuery->result();
foreach ($result as $key=> $value) {
    //echo "<pre>";
    print_r($value);

    $day = "MONTH(date_of_created) = DATE(CURRENT_DATE())";
    $group = "f_id IN (SELECT MAX(f_id) FROM tbl_fileStatus GROUP BY f_bankid)";
    $condiion = "and ba.createdby='" . $value->id . "' and " . $day ." and " . $group;
    $query2 = "
        select
            (SELECT COUNT(c_id)
             FROM tbl_lead
             WHERE leadstatus='1' AND ".$day.") as confirmCount,

            (SELECT COUNT(f_id)
             FROM tbl_fileStatus as fs
             join tbl_bankdata as ba on ba.bank_id=fs.f_bankid
             WHERE fs.f_filestatus=1 " . $condiion . ") as disbursed,

            (SELECT COUNT(f_id)
             FROM tbl_fileStatus as fs
             join tbl_bankdata as ba on ba.bank_id=fs.f_bankid
             WHERE fs.f_filestatus=2 ".$condiion.") as filesubmit
    ";
    # code...
    $getQuery2= $this->db->query($query2);
    $result2[]=$getQuery2->result();
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r(result2);
```

`$result` looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 1
        [firstname] => xyz
        [lastname] => xyz
    )
    ...
)
```

Second query output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [fallowCall] => 0
            [confirmCount] => 0
            [disbursed] => 0
            [filesubmit] => 0
        )
    )
    ...
)
```

How can I produce the correct results which relate respective employees with with their performance metrics?  Either this structure:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 1
        [firstname] => xyz
        [lastname] => xyz
        [somename] => (
            [fallowCall] => 0
            [confirmCount] => 0
            [disbursed] => 0
            [filesubmit] => 0
        )
    )
    ...
)
```

Or this structure:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 1
        [firstname] => xyz
        [lastname] => xyz
        [fallowCall] => 0
        [confirmCount] => 0
        [disbursed] => 0
        [filesubmit] => 0
    )
    ...
)
```

I have added the my table structure and some sample data here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8MoWmKPuzTrrC3DQJsiX35/0

**some notes here**

1) `createdby` is the id of table `tbl_employee`

2) `lead_id` in the bank table is the `c_id` of the table `tbl_lead`

3) `f_bankid` in the `tbl_fileStatus` is the `bank_id` of the table `tbl_bankdata`

Comment: @mickmackusa, "multidimensional structure? " because I am getting the employee details and in the second query I have some details related to the employee and all the details I have to display in the list. So I thought that my expected can help me to solve

Comment: Till now I have zero counts. This is an example. about somename, I thought it will be a good way to do. I can use this output also [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [firstname] => xyz
                [lastname] => xyz
                [fallowCall] => 0
                [confirmCount] => 0
  [disbursed] => 0
                [filesubmit] => 0
                    
            )

Comment: @mickmackusa, In your first query I am getting the error  #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.I think if we go with array then it will be good and there are more changes to increse the subquery in the future.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I created the table strcture and updated in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough fiddle data to generate non-zero counts.  Having a mix of qualifying data and non-qualifying data for intended queries makes verifying a "working solution" easier to test/visualize.  (Then update the demo link.)  Also please delete old comments under this question that have no future value to researchers/volunteers.  My workday ends in 3 hours, I'll check back then.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I just change the link and updated table. Kindly check that

Comment: @mickmackusa, Sure, I will not repeat this in future. Deleted old comments

Comment: @mickmackusa, Have you found any solution on this? and Can you request to reopen my question?

Comment: @mickmackusa, Whatever information I have that I provided in the question. I need to know what information do you want more?

Comment: try with this : `$result= $getQuery->result();
foreach ($result as $key=> $value) 
{
    $query2 = 'your query in foreach loop';
    $value->somename = $getQuery2->result();
}
print_r($result);`

Comment: @Pradeep, Thanks for the reply, Give me sometime to check again your code

Comment: @Pradeep, Yes, It's working. I just need to know if I have to access the samename value then how can I access it? I tried  print_r($row->somename[0]->disbursed); but it's not working.

Comment: @Pradeep answering questions with comments intentionally breaks Stack Overflow page design.  Please do not do this.  If the answer was merely how to declare an object inside an object, this question would be a duplicate. There is actually no compelling reason to create the sub-object. I intend to show the OP how to write better code.  I had to spend time with my family, but now I have time to volunteer.

Comment: @mickmackusa, Because of this question is closed and I already added all the information as per you suggested.

Comment: `fallowCall` and `tbl_leadUpload` are missing from your fiddle.  Please update your fiddle with the missing information.

Comment: @mickmackusa, Yes., It's good to spend time with family. I am really happy that you guide me to improve the question. But now my issue got resolved.  I am getting my expected output. I request you to reopen my question so that Pradeep can add the answer here.

Comment: Again, it is not beneficial for Stack Overflow to have questions reopened, then reclosed as a duplicate of another question.  The only way this question should be reopened is if it is clear, complete, and unique to Stack Overflow.  The only way I can help you and reopen this page is to give you more than you asked for  -- better sql.  I am currently working on a solution for you, but you have not offered all of your db data.

Comment: Opening your question as it is now, I would then have to instantly re-hammer it closed with this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43573578/2943403  Should I keep working your sql or am I wasting my time?  (FYI, your query won't work as desired as it is currently written.)

Comment: @mickmackusa, I remove the tbl_leadUpload subquery. So I don't think so it is require as of now.

Comment: @user9437856 Please review this single-query technique that intends to provide your complete result set.  I don't precisely know what the expected result is from your sample data -- I will need you to tell me what is expected if my result set is incorrect.  You may like to trial it within your project to double check that the logic remains true with your real database data.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8MoWmKPuzTrrC3DQJsiX35/1  If it is correct, I will explain my sql in my answer after the page is reopened.

Comment: @mickmackusa, Thanks for your reply. Let me check this with my query.

Comment: Still checking? @user9437856

Comment: @mickmackusa, Apologize for the late reply, As per your query, MAX(confirmedLeads.confirmCount) displaying 3 for all the employees which are wrong. So I am coordinating with one of my team members who created the database structure for discussed the output but unfortunately he is not available due to fever.

Comment: @user9437856 That makes sense.  I have replaced the CROSS JOIN with a LEFT JOIN so that the qualifying lead counts are related only to employee id.  I've also added a lead row which doesn't have an associated fileStatus entry to show data independence.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8MoWmKPuzTrrC3DQJsiX35/2  (the results WILL change when May becomes June ...then the sample entry dates will need to be bumped up one month)

Comment: As per my knowledge, Output is correct. I need know this  SUM(IF(fileStatus.f_filestatus = 1, 1, 0)) AS disbursedThisMonth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually no  need to create the additional depth/complexity just to hold the count data.  Furthermore, by using a combination of LEFT JOINs to connect the related tables and apply your required conditional rules, you can achieve your desired result by making just one trip to the database.  This will without question provide superior efficiency for your application.  LEFT JOINs are important to use so that counts can be zero without excluding employees from the result set.

Also, I should point out that your attempted query was mistakenly comparing a `MONTH()` value against a `DATE()` value -- that was never going to end well. :)  In fact, to ensure that your sql is accurately isolating the current month from the current year, you need to be also checking the YEAR value.

My recommended sql:

```
SELECT
    employees.id,
    employees.firstname,
    employees.lastname,
    COUNT(DISTINCT leads.c_id) AS leadsThisMonth,
    SUM(IF(fileStatus.f_filestatus = 1, 1, 0)) AS disbursedThisMonth,
    SUM(IF(fileStatus.f_filestatus = 2, 1, 0)) AS filesubmitThisMonth
FROM tbl_employee AS employees

LEFT JOIN tbl_lead AS leads
    ON employees.id = leads.createdby
        AND leadstatus = 1 
        AND MONTH(leads.date_of_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
        AND YEAR(leads.date_of_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())                                                 

LEFT JOIN tbl_bankdata AS bankData
    ON employees.id = bankData.createdby

LEFT JOIN tbl_fileStatus AS fileStatus
    ON bankData.bank_id = fileStatus.f_bankid
        AND MONTH(fileStatus.date_of_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
        AND YEAR(fileStatus.date_of_created) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
        AND fileStatus.f_id = (
                SELECT MAX(subFileStatus.f_id)
                FROM tbl_fileStatus AS subFileStatus
                WHERE subFileStatus.f_bankid = bankData.bank_id
                GROUP BY subFileStatus.f_bankid
            )

WHERE employees.is_archive = 0
    AND employees.is_approved = 1

GROUP BY employees.id, employees.firstname, employees.lastname
```

The `SUM(IF())` expression is a technique used to execute a "conditional count".  "Aggregate data" is formed by using GROUP BY and there are specialized "[aggregate functions](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-in-mysql.php)" which must be used to create linear/flat data from these clusters/non-flat collections of data.  `fileStatus` data is effectively piled up upon itself due to the GROUP BY call.  If `COUNT(fileStatus.f_filestatus)` was called, it would count all of the rows in the cluster.  Since you wish to differentiate between `f_filestatus = 1` and `f_filestatus = 2`, an `IF()` statement is used.  This is doing the same thing as `COUNT()` (adding 1 for every qualifying occurrence), but it is different from `COUNT()` in that it does not count specific rows (within the scope of the cluster) unless the `IF()` expression is satisfied.  [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075505/mysql-is-it-possible-to-sum-if-or-to-count-if).

Here is a db fiddle demo with some adjustments to your supplied sample data: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8MoWmKPuzTrrC3DQJsiX35/4  (The result set will only be "good" while the current is June of this year.)

After saving the above string as `$sql`, you can simply execute it and loop through the array of objects like this:

```
foreach ($this->db->query($sql)->result() as $object) {
    // these are the properties available in each object
    // $object->id
    // $object->firstname
    // $object->lastname
    // $object->leadsThisMonth
    // $object->disbursedThisMonth
    // $object->filesubmitThisMonth
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and I really appreciate your support and guide for the better question. the answer is working for me. I haven't understood this fileStatus.f_filestatus = 1, 1, 0). if possible can you share any link where i can learn this